# Set a picture to ActiveX Control in Matlab Gui

Tags: matlab, user-interface, activex

In Matlab GUI, if I created a new **ActiveX Control** of type **Microsoft Forms 2.0 Image** , The value of property `picture` in the **property inspector** window is set to `null` and can't be changed.

Then, How to set image to this component ?

Comment: see this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5848/Using-ActiveX-Control-Inside-MATLAB

Comment: @RachelGallen: Not helpful enough and code samples throw errors :(